# How to set a placeholder into a non-Thymeleaf parameter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, android-pay, google-pay

I am trying to implement SaveToAndroidPay button on my html page, created with Thymeleaf. I have a parameter in context specified from Spring's back-end called **jwt**.

```
<g:savetoandroidpay jwt="<<<HERE>>>" size="small" theme="light" ></g:savetoandroidpay>
```

How can I set this parameter into non-thymeleaf attribute (jwt)?
Both ${jwt} and [[${jwt}]] are not working.

Comment: I don't know if I get you right, but you could try something like this: th:attr="jwt=${#servletContext.getAttribute(jwt)}"

Comment: @Flocke it seems to work! You can post it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Flocke actually for me worked just th:attr="jwt=${jwt}", without servletContext

Comment: thanks, but Metroids' answer is better then mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Thymeleaf 3, you can simply prefix the attribute with `th:`.  So:

```
<g:savetoandroidpay th:jwt="${jwt}" size="small" theme="light" ></g:savetoandroidpay>
```

If you're using Thymeleaf 2 (this works in Thymeleaf 3 as well), you can also just use th:attr, as was commented:

```
<g:savetoandroidpay th:attr="jtw = ${jwt}" size="small" theme="light" ></g:savetoandroidpay>
```